# Cant close the loop for a exception-handling

Tags: python, exception

I am new to python. I have python 3.7.3
I'm trying a simple exception handling, but somehow get stuck at closing it.

```
try:
 print(1/0)
except ZeroDivisionErroe as e:
 print('You cant divide by zero, youre silly.')
finally:
 print('Goodbye, world!)'

>>> try:
...  print(1/0)
... except ZeroDivisionErroe as e:
...  print('You cant divide by zero, youre silly.')
... finally:
...  print('Goodbye, world!)'
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo - `ZeroDivisionErroe` should be `ZeroDivisionError`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have only two errors:

- `ZeroDivisionError`: this was spelled wrong
- `print('Goodbye, world!')` : the close quote should be placed before the close paranthesis

Below is your code after the alterations:

```
try: 
    print(1/0) 
except ZeroDivisionError as e: 
    print('You cant divide by zero, youre silly.') 
finally: 
    print('Goodbye, world!')
```